# Wrong ivy resolved files in cache

Tags: ivy

I am confused by the resolved properties/xml file in Ivy cache. For some reason, I see some files with proper names like these (

resolved-ccm-ccmJaqual2-129390.properties
resolved-ccm-ccmJaqual2-129390.xml

And some files with *working@hostname.*

resolved-ccm-ccmJaqual2-working@windev7.properties
resolved-ccm-ccmJaqual2-working@windev7.xml

I know these files are being used somehow by ivy.publish (implicitly calls ivy.delivery). Could any Ivy experts here kindly explain how these suppose to work?

Thanks

Comment: What's the issue? You stated that the cache contains incorrect data? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Mark. I can't find any explanation from Ivy doc about these resolved file so I don't know how to this works. Are the names of these resolved*working@hostname correct? Why not name them with real revision number? I see the dynamic revision of the dependencies are not replaced by the static version, so what purpose do these files serve?